# Any PHP oAuth code leads to 500 internal server error

Tags: php, apache, oauth

Probably something do with the server. I'm on the EC2 bitnami LAMP stack. I've tried Zend, the official oauth.net library, etc. Just those files lead to 500 internal server error.

The code I'm using is the simple example provided by google. 
http://pastebin.com/C3dZ55UK

The logs on my server didn't have anything about these particular files.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd put in some debugging statements to see where the 500 is triggered. At a guess, it might be due to the external URL - maybe this is prohibited in your PHP install?

Answer (score 0):

Add error logging on the top of your file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

It might be dependent on [allow_furl_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) which might be switched off if you're on shared hosting.